# Script doesn't run at startup no matter what

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, keyboard, login

I have a script located at `/opt/capslock_delay_fix.sh`.
I want the script to run after login.

I've tried everything. From Startup Apps, to `.bash_rc`, to `.profile`. It just won't run the script. I wonder if the script itself will only work at a certain moment after login.

Here is the content of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
xkbcomp -xkb "$DISPLAY" - | sed 's#key <CAPS>.*#key <CAPS> {\
    repeat=no,\
    type[group1]="ALPHABETIC",\
    symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock],\
    actions[group1]=[ LockMods(modifiers=Lock),\
    Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3)]\
};\
#' | xkbcomp -w 0 - "$DISPLAY"
```

Comment: Run it with a break: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 25 && <script>"`, where `<script>` is the path to your script. Always the case with keyboard and touchpad  commands. Someone please convert it into an answer.

Comment: Is the script file executable (`chmod +x /path/to/file`)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Didn't do the job. The problem remains, after adding that line of code to my `.profile`. I've noticed a slight delay between logging in and the interface showing up.

Comment: Also when you use the command as startup application? Then: does it run correctly from the terminal?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Same thing after adding it to the Startup Applications. Also tried adding to `.bash_profile`. Command works as expected if I type it in manually at the terminal.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I take that back! Seems it works after a few seconds (maybe I tried it too soon).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Changed it to `sleep 2` and it still works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi catgocat, great! I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain types of commands and scripts almost by definition break, if they run too early in the log in process. A few examples are: keyboard- and touchpad- related commands, monitor settings (`xrandr`) and such. Even indicators sometimes.

The reason is that either the command breaks if the desktop isn't ready for it, or the command is overruled afterwards by local procedures.

Including a little break will do the job then, in the format:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && <command>"
```